# CART as junior synonym to Decision Tree

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I would recommend to make "cart" and "classification-tree" tags junior synonyms of "decision-tree". Because, often CART acronym is regarded to be just a particular *method* or algorithm of the tree building, along with other methods such as CHAID or QUEST. Decision Tree seems currently to be the most omnibus term.

Comment: Hi @ttnphns! I am looking through the old [tag-synonyms] threads on meta and I came across this old post of yours. The situation has changed since you posted this question and currently [classification-tree], [decision-trees], and [tree] -- **all of them are synonyms of [cart]** which is the master tag (with almost 500 questions). Do you think it's okay to leave it like that, or would you still suggest that some other tag should be the master tag? Which one then?

Comment: @amoeba, `cart` or `crt`  is OK for me _because_ it is `classification/regression tree`. I just wanted to say that the _abbrebiation_ `CART` historically stood for a specific algorithm only.

Comment: I see. Perhaps in this case consider accepting gung's answer to make this thread visually appear as resolved. I found it because I was looking through the meta [tag-synonyms] threads without an accepted answer...

Answer (score 3):

Some relevant facts:

- We seem to have four tags related to this discussion: [cart](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cart), [decision-trees](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-trees), [tree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree), & [classification-tree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification-tree).
- At present, [*decision-trees* & *tree* are synonyms that automatically map to *cart*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/cart/info).  On the other hand, [*classification-tree* is distinct, but indexes only two threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification-tree), one of which is also categorized under *cart*.
- It's also worth recognizing that [making a tag a synonym makes it much more difficult to find questions categorized under the old tag, and this problem has not been resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135466/how-can-you-find-questions-with-ses-search-features-that-have-now-defunct-tags).

The points you raise are good ones, but I agree with @whuber that it might not be best to change the current pattern of synonyms.  My suggestion would be to edit cart's tag wiki excerpt to indicate more accurately how it ought to be viewed / used by the community.  There is a linguistic [phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) in English (and probably all languages) whereby the name of a particularly salient member of a category comes to stand for the category as a whole.  (For example, [Kleenex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleenex) is a proprietary / brand name, but is used to indicate any facial tissue.)  I can imagine "cart" coming to be used (perhaps incorrectly) the same way.

Comment: It is better to avoid arcronyms as tags altogether! And not to submit to "salient category becoming generic label" phenomenon when possible. I see you don't agree with me, but my opinion is there: "classification-tree' (if not 'decision-tree') in place of 'cart'. [Also, 'principal-components' for 'pca', 'anaysis-of-variance' for 'anova']

Answer (score 1):

Because a [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) is a generic method that goes well beyond CART or classification, I would be reluctant to make it a synonym.

Comment: Well, perhaps you find it excessively broad. Then, maybe, create a senior tag 'classification-regression-tree'? Instead of 'cart'. It is that last _acronym_ that makes me frown, because historically it is associated with CART (or CRT) algorithm by _Breiman et al. 1984. Classification and Regression
Trees_. This algo is just a particular method. CHAID tree method by _Kass, G. 1980. An exploratory technique for investigating large quantities of categorical data_ appeared even earlier.

Comment: P.S. or, alternatively, recognize 'classification-tree' as the senior tag. After all, the tree is splitting into subgroups, i.e. it is always a (hierarchical) _classification_.